# jQuery Validate - Dynamic errorLabelContainer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have this snippet:

```
$('#my-form').validate({
      errorLabelContainer: $('#error-div-1'),
      submitHandler: function (form) {
         $(form).ajaxSubmit(formOptions);
      }
});
```

Is it possible to update `errorLabelContainer` later? For example, change it from `#error-div-1` to `#error-div-2` like the example below :

```
$( "#toggle-container" ).click(function() {
     errorLabelContainer: $('#error-div-2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to update errorLabelContainer later?
>
> `$( "#toggle-container" ).click(function() {
>        errorLabelContainer: $('#error-div-2');
>   });`

**No**.  It's not possible to put `key:value` pairs meant for the settings object inside the `.validate()` method inside of a random handler `function`.  Nor is it possible to call `.validate()` a second time to over-ride previous settings.  Once `.validate()` initializes the plugin on your `form` with its settings, all subsequent calls to this method are ignored.  The developer provides no method for dynamically reinitializing the plugin with new settings.

Since `errorLabelContainer` is only meant for setting the *type of container* for the dynamic messages such as, `label`, `div`, `span`, etc, you have to closely re-examine your whole approach.  There is no reason to put an `id` in there.  The plugin's `errorPlacement` is used to tell it where to "generically" insert this message.  By default, they are inserted just *after* each input element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Sparky . Is there an alternative to achieve what I'm trying to achieve : Define a specific `errorLabelContainer` by selecting it with `id` or `class` and then change it later?

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi, it's entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve by wanting to do this.  However, just what you're asking is not possible, and as explained, would not be good practice.